# Triplet prime reciprocal series

Tags: number-theory

Does any body know if the series of reciprocals of triplet primes of form $p, p+2, p+6$ or $p, p+4, p+6$ converges or diverges? Could this be used as a proof of infinity of twin primes?

Answer (score 6):

It is a well-known result that through [Brun's sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun_sieve) it is possible to prove that the series of the reciprocals of the twin primes converges, hence your series are converging, too. As a reference, see Halberstam, *Sieve methods*.

However, the fact that:
$$\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathcal{P}\\p+2\in\mathcal{P}}}\frac{1}{p}<+\infty$$
does not imply anything about the infinitude of twin primes. It just implies that they cannot be too "dense" in $\mathbb{N}$.